# Форматирование даты и времени в kotlinx-datetime в kotlin multiplatform

Tags: kotlin, форматирование, kotlin-multiplatform

Собственно, мучал меня данный вопрос долго, но я не находит подходящих решений. Кроме того, известные методы из JVM, например, для форматирования даты и времени, казались мне неудобными из-за того, что нужно всё время следить за тем, что форматная строка соответствует документации. А дело ведь в том, что у меня нет нужды хранить форматную строку для даты где-то в БД. Они у меня вообще редко меняются и наглухо захардкожены. Можно, конечно, собрать строку по шаблону при помощи известных возможностей kotlin, но какие-то длинные они получались. И это не считая того, что нужно было следить за дополнением количества лет, например, до 4-х цифр.

Answer (score 0):

Решение нашёл простое, как мне кажется, но идеально подходящее под описанную мною ситуацию. На случай, если у кого есть схожие проблемы, делюсь ответом тут. На GitHub не выкладываю потому, как кусок кода совсем не большой и делать из него библиотеку смысла я не вижу. Берите, пользуйтесь и усовершенствуйте все, кто пожелает.

```kotlin
fun String.complementLeft(complementUpto: Int, complement: String) =
    if (length >= complementUpto) this
    else (complementUpto - length).let { delta ->
        complement.repeat(delta / complement.length + (if (delta % complement.length != 0) 1 else 0)) + this
    }

import kotlinx.datetime.*

@Suppress("PropertyName", "unused", "SpellCheckingInspection")
open class KotlinDateFormat(private val date: LocalDate) {
    val yyyy by lazy { date.year format 4 }
    val yy by lazy { date.year format 2 }
    val DDD by lazy { date.dayOfYear format 3 }
    val MM by lazy { date.monthNumber format 2 }
    val LL by lazy { date.month.name }
    val LLLL by lazy { date.month.name }
    val EE by lazy { date.dayOfWeek.name }
    val dd by lazy { date.dayOfMonth format 2 }
    protected infix fun Number.format(count: Int) = toString().run {
        if (length < count) complementLeft(count, "0")
        else if (length > count) substring((length - count) until length)
        else this
    }
}

val LocalDateTime.isPM get() = hour >= 12
val LocalDateTime.isAM get() = !isPM
val LocalDateTime.ampm get() = if (isAM) "am" else "pm"
val LocalDateTime.AMPM get() = if (isAM) "AM" else "PM"


@Suppress("PropertyName", "unused", "SpellCheckingInspection")
open class KotlinDateTimeFormat(private val time: LocalDateTime) : KotlinDateFormat(time.date) {
    val aa by lazy { time.ampm }
    val AA by lazy { time.AMPM }
    val hh by lazy { (time.hour % 12) format 2 }
    val HH by lazy { time.hour format 2 }
    val mm by lazy { time.minute format 2 }
    val ss by lazy { time.second format 2 }
    val nn by lazy { time.nanosecond format 9 }
}

fun LocalDate.toString(format: KotlinDateFormat.() -> String): String = KotlinDateFormat(this).format()

fun LocalDateTime.toString(format: KotlinDateTimeFormat.() -> String): String = KotlinDateTimeFormat(this).format()

fun Instant.toString(
    timeZone: TimeZone = TimeZone.currentSystemDefault(),
    format: KotlinDateTimeFormat.() -> String
): String = KotlinDateTimeFormat(this.toLocalDateTime(timeZone)).format()
```

Использовать сие следует как-то так:

```kotlin
val created: Instant
// тут какой-то код
created.toString { "$yyyy.$MM.$dd $HH:$mm:$ss" }}
```

Решение имеет недостатки. Например, вывод текста не локализован. Если кто дополнит, милости прошу.